# Searching many sheets for values and put the results in one sheet

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, flatten

I have a list of employee with dates for leaves they got each month, those dates are different of course, now i want to create one sheet for all leaves to showcase all leaves they taken through year, not depending on the row but depending on the name of the employee

I tried to use query but its not working well for me, any idea please?

Sheet link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y-L5ICc-HWHYpkD_caxy2isTTHYVYCFBoCORQa5UJo4/edit#gid=833452873

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either use:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(TEXT(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SUBSTITUTE(
 {'1'!A2:A;'2'!A2:A;'3'!A2:A}, " ", CHAR(13))&"×"&{'1'!B2:F;'2'!B2:F;'3'!B2:F}), "×")), {"@", "dd/mm/yyyy"}), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 <> '30/12/1899' group by Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), " ")))
```

[image]

---

or in B2:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(TEXT(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SUBSTITUTE(
 {'1'!A2:A;'2'!A2:A;'3'!A2:A}, " ", CHAR(13))&"×"&{'1'!B2:F;'2'!B2:F;'3'!B2:F}), "×")), {"@", "dd/mm/yyyy"}), 
 "select max(Col2) where Col2 <> '30/12/1899' group bY Col2 pivot Col1"),,9^9)), " ")), {2,3,4,5,6}, )))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Player0. the first formula is working well, but when i add more columns to the range to search in, it doesnt show all the data. "&{'1'!B2:F;'2'!B2:F;'3'!B2:F}.

Comment: oh i changed this and added more numbers and it worked like charm {2,3,4,5,6}. thank you so much again Player0

Answer (score 1):

I duplicated your DB tab and entered the following in A2:

`={unique({'1'!A2:A;'2'!A2:A;'3'!A2:A}),index(trim(split(transpose(query(if((index(split(flatten(query({'1'!A2:A;'2'!A2:A;'3'!A2:A}&"❄️"&{'1'!B2:C;'2'!B2:C;'3'!B2:C},"where not Col1 matches '^❄️$'")),"❄️"),,1)<>transpose(unique({'1'!A2:A;'2'!A2:A;'3'!A2:A})))+(index(split(flatten(query({'1'!A2:A;'2'!A2:A;'3'!A2:A}&"❄️"&{'1'!B2:C;'2'!B2:C;'3'!B2:C},"where not Col1 matches '^❄️$'")),"❄️"),,2)=""),,text(index(split(flatten(query({'1'!A2:A;'2'!A2:A;'3'!A2:A}&"❄️"&{'1'!B2:C;'2'!B2:C;'3'!B2:C},"where not Col1 matches '^❄️$'")),"❄️"),,2),"m/d/yyyy")),,9^9))," ")))}`

Your dates format are inconsistent though. Some are d/m/yyyy others are m/d/yyyy so you should fix that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. its working but when i try to add more sheets and columns as of here "&{'1'!B2:C;'2'!B2:C;'3'!B2:C} the sheet lags so much. in fact i have about 50 columns so thats why i guess its lagging. but anyway thank you so much.